# Want to make two commit in one commit

Tags: git

I am trying to make two commit in one and push it to a new branch, I tried to use `git rebase -i` but nothing worked

Comment: You have to `squash` this 2 commits. You can follow this example -> https://www.internalpointers.com/post/squash-commits-into-one-git

Comment: You need to tell it how many commits to rebase on, `git rebase -i HEAD~2`

Comment: i have two commit example A and B and i want au push B with code commit A

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an alternative, you can also

```
git checkout -b new_branch
git reset --soft HEAD~2  # rewinds HEAD back 2 commits while keeping changes
git commit -m "Message for both commits"
git push origin HEAD
```

if you're not fond of interactive rebasing or don't feel confident enough with it.

---

Before :

```
X---A---B <<< your_branch
```

After :

```
X---A---B <<< your_branch
 \
  C <<< new_branch
```

where `C` contains cumulative changes of `A` and `B`, like after a squash.